# How to use media queries to change between table and list depending on screen size?

Tags: html, css

When my website is in mobile phone screen size, I want some information to be displayed as a list. When my website is in a larger screen size I want that same bit of information to be displayed as a table. How do I do this?

Another possibility is to change the direction of the table headers, so instead of running along the top of the table from left to right, they start in the top-left corner and run from top to bottom, the information being displayed horizontally running from left to right. Is this possible?

I only know HTML and CSS, so only solutions using these languages are viable at the moment. Thank you!

Comment: Why not make both a list and a table, and then hide the list on desktop and hide the table on mobile?

Answer (score 1):

##### This is not what `table` is intended for.

If you want to preserve the look and feel of a table while also making it responsive, try out [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

To accomplish this functionality, we can use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to toggle the [`flex-wrap: wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) style.

The example below wraps the columns when the screen width is smaller than 600px.

```css
.row{
  display:flex;
}
.row.headers div{
  background-color:lightgrey;
}
.row div{
  width:100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .row{
    flex-wrap:wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row headers">
  <div>Header 1</div><div>Header 2</div><div>Header 3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>Column 1</div><div>Column 2</div><div>Column 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, this is what I get for not coding for two months... I totally forgot about the media queries in css...

Answer (score 0):

Alright let's see if I can figure this out. On mobile you want some information to be displayed as a list and on larger screens you want some information to be displayed a table. To do this I'll use Javascript to append lists and tables according to the screen size. It's not efficient however, you should probably be using JQuery. Attached is a snippet that indicates that an unordered list should only appear on screens less than or equal to 650 px (mobile devices).

**EDIT**

Okay scratch the Javascript, as you can see in the above answer media queries in css are the way to go.

```js
window.onload = () => {
    if(window.innerWidth <= 650) {
  const mainDiv = document.querySelector('.main');
     const list = document.createElement('ul');
     const listItemOne = document.createElement('li');
     const listItemTwo = document.createElement('li');
     const listItemThree = document.createElement('li');
     listItemOne.textContent = "one";
     listItemTwo.textContent = "two";
     listItemThree.textContent = "three";
     list.appendChild(listItemOne);
     list.appendChild(listItemTwo);
     list.appendChild(listItemThree);
     mainDiv.appendChild(list);
     }
     

}
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPEhtml>
<html> 
<head>
  <title></title>
</head> 
<body> 
  <div class = "main">
  
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```